# Application insights middleware - Track SQL parameters

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

**Problem**: Application insights by default [does not track SQL parameters in dependencies telemetry](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/775). I want to either enable parameter tracking or manually add parameters.

**Little background**: I had .Net Core 2 app with application insights. I was reading request body and saving it as custom property with `TelemetryInitializer`. I migrated to .Net Core 3 where I was not able to use `TelemetryInitializer` anymore as .Net Core 3 [disabled synchronous IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0#http-synchronous-io-disabled-in-all-servers). Similar issue described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1872). So I have implemented application insights middleware as per this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking#http-request-in-owin-self-hosted-app). I am using `EF Core` for all my database access.

**Question**: I found this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/193) which says that it is possible to "access SqlCommand operation detail in TelemetryInitializer". But how can I achieve this using application insights middleware?

Comment: How do you access the database, using SqlCommands etc or using entity Framework for example?

Comment: Using EF Core. I will update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to write asp.net core middleware for this. Instead you should be using a TelemetryInitializer. Given an intializer like this:

```cs
public class CustomInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (!(telemetry is DependencyTelemetry supportedTelemetry))
            return;

        if (supportedTelemetry.Type == "SQL" && supportedTelemetry.TryGetOperationDetail("SqlCommand", out var command))
        {
            foreach (DbParameter parameter in ((SqlCommand)command).Parameters)
            {
                supportedTelemetry.Properties.Add(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why you say

> I migrated to .Net Core 3 where I was not able to use TelemetryInitializer anymore as .Net Core 3 disabled synchronous IO

I use TelemetryInitializers all the time.

I see the parameters as custom properties in App Insights:

[image]

For reference: I used this code in my controller, based on [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli):

```cs
using (var bc = new BloggingContext())
{
    bc.Database.EnsureCreated();
    await bc.Blogs.AddAsync(new Blog
    {
        Url = "www.blank.com",
        Rating = 0
    });
    await bc.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: I am also reading request body, but since .Net Core 3 I do not want to do it sync and `TelemetryInitializer` has only void method. Similar issue described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1872). So I am using middlewre to ready request body async. I wonder if it's possible to use middleware and telemetryInitializer together.

Comment: You can still add the request body to your request telemetry using [this middleware](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/686#issuecomment-530353448) as an example. And have the parameter values logged as properties to your sql dependency telemetry using the telemetry initializer as proposed. The request and dependency telemetry can be correlated using the operationId. I wouldn't log the full request body in *all* telemetry due to costs and speed